# JMeter Java HEAP issue seen after finished test plan execution

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, out-of-memory, jmeter-maven-plugin

JMeter Test seems to finish fine.

But the next output after "14:48:37 [info] Completed Test: needs_gcs_load_test.jmx" is missing because of the heap issue.

Next lines should normally be,

```
[INFO] Test Results:
[INFO]  
[INFO] Tests Run: 1, Failures: 0
```

Any ideas...?

### Have increased heap to 2048. Also removed debug in jmx.log file.

HEAP issue.

```
14:48:37 [info]   Interpreted + native   Method                        
14:48:37 [info] 100.0%     0  + 27207    java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0
14:48:37 [info] 100.0%     0  + 27207    Total interpreted
14:48:37 [info] 
14:48:37 [info] 
14:48:37 [info] Global summary of 301.00 seconds:
14:48:37 [info] 100.0% 27326             Received ticks
14:48:37 [info]   0.2%    46             Received GC ticks
14:48:37 [info]   6.5%  1785             Compilation
14:48:37 [info]   0.0%     1             Deoptimization
14:48:37 [info]   0.0%     2             Other VM operations
14:48:37 [info]   0.0%     8             Class loader
14:48:37 [info]   0.0%     6             Unknown code
14:48:37 [info] Completed Test: needs_gcs_load_test.jmx
14:48:38 [ERROR] Java heap space -> [Help 1]
14:48:38 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
14:48:38    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:57)
14:48:38    at java.nio.CharBuffer.allocate(CharBuffer.java:335)
14:48:38    at java.util.Scanner.makeSpace(Scanner.java:840)
14:48:38    at java.util.Scanner.readInput(Scanner.java:795)
14:48:38    at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Scanner.java:1685)
14:48:38    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.FailureScanner.hasTestFailed(FailureScanner.java:36)
14:48:38    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.JMeterMojo.parseTestResults(JMeterMojo.java:70)
14:48:38    at com.lazerycode.jmeter.JMeterMojo.execute(JMeterMojo.java:54)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
14:48:38    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
14:48:38    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
14:48:38    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:48:38    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:48:38    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:48:38    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
14:48:38    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
14:48:38    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
14:48:38    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:181)
14:48:38    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
14:48:38    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
14:48:38    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:48:38    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
14:48:38    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
14:48:38    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
14:48:38 [ERROR] 
14:48:38 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
14:48:38 [ERROR] 
14:48:38 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
14:48:38 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/OutOfMemoryError
14:48:38 channel stopped
14:48:38 Archiving artifacts
14:48:40 Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 1% sets the build as unstable
14:48:40 Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 2% sets the build as failure
14:48:40 
14:48:40 
14:48:40 
14:48:40 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Increase Heap Site ? What do you expect?

Comment: I tried 3072 MB too. No change.

Since the test seems to finish fine, I thought maybe someone seen something similar..?  But maybe it's normal that the JMeter memory issue is seen after the "test complete", i.e. when the test result is supposed to be handled/printed...?

Comment: Have you tried to run the test inside an IDE if you get the same issue?

Comment: Are you using jmeter 3.2 and latest JMeter Maven plugin?

Comment: Close this question now.